# Foreign Key check against 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a single table that needs a ForeignKey constraint (or constraints) between 2 columns. I'm storing information in column A and column B, that needs to be unique no matter which of those columns the data is present in (can't insert a duplicate entry into A if the value is already present somewhere in B, and vice-versa).

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I already have a UNIQUE for both A and B, so they shouldn't have any duplicate entries separately, but I have noticed that some data from A is present in B and I'd really like to prevent it.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a way to do this constraint automatically. You can put it in a trigger.

Comment: This isn't a foreign key constraint. A foreign key *requires* that there be a match for the column, it doesn't prohibit it.

Comment: Can you explain the use case for this? Maybe there's a better design that only uses one column, which you can then declare unique.

Comment: What normal form are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think you may need to redesign your database structure. If there is a reason to use this structure or … , please explain more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand you currently have:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  A INT NOT NULL,
  B INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (A),
  UNIQUE KEY (B)
);
```

You want the set of `A` unioned with `B` to also be unique.

It sounds like you have a multi-valued attribute that you're trying to store in two columns `A` and `B`, even though they are in fact the same logical attribute.

Here's a way to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE foo_child (
  AB INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  foo_id INT NOT NULL,
  device_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(foo_id)
);
```

With this, the set of values `AB` must be unique. You can have two (or more) of these values associated with the same `foo_id`.

Although what it lacks is a constraint that makes sure that each `foo` entity has exactly two of the child values.